# Can I play my animation in full screen without rendering?

Tags: animation, blend-files

I made an animation and I want to see it playing without all these menus, lines etc. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start playing the animation and then, in the screen layout menu, you can simply choose "3D View Full" for remove all the menus and display it.
[image]

Comment: I don't have that option in Blender 2.78c

Comment: The `3D View Full` screen layout is a default layout provided by blender, it wasn't always there (added in 2.64) so copying settings when upgrading could prevent it being added, it can be created and added to your startup blend if desired. There are also [other fullscreen options](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77830/935). There is an `Only Render` [display option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html) to hide widgets, grid and relationship lines.