# Strip Blender Down for just modeling

Tags: interface, customization

Please keep in mind I am not trying to offend anyone!!! I realize that Blender is a powerful and a wonderfully free tool for people wanting to learn every inch of being a 3d artist and animator. However is there a way strip away stuff I am never going to use? It is just so cluttered I really only need a way to make 3 model's, Maybe a way to texture the models but even so I hear there are better tools for doing that? The Unreal Engine which is the game engine I am working with at current so I don't need the blender one. I have no interest in making short films or using the other tools in the package.

Comment: Yes, if you have a strong programming skillset, and a detailed knowledge of the code used for Blender, since Blender is open source,*theoretically* one could do what you describe. Otherwise, practically speaking for the typical end user, no, it is not likely to be possible to strip out material like you describe. You can, however, hide much of it as 3pointedits answer outlines.

Comment: Yeah I didn't really think it would possible with out disecting the code and as you stated needs to be someone that really knows what they are doing. Thanks anyway's for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Blender allows you to save your preferred setup as a default, just turn off what you don't want to see and go to File > Save Startup File

[image: Startup file]

Comment: I will have to try that when I get home. Thanks for the answer

Comment: It would be worth looking at adjusting the [screen layouts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/screens.html) to taste before saving the startup file so that the layouts are always available. There is already a 3dview full  setup that removes everything but the 3d view. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/77830/935) may also be of interest.