# Is there a way to remove dublicate objects on top of each other in Object Mode?

Tags: .fbx, object-mode

I have imported an fbx file of huge size with millions of verts. It seems something has gone wrong and unity file was converted into fbx with some errors.

There are around 5 dublicate objects on each object.

[image]

Is there any quick way to remove those dublicates without spending too much time on deleting objects manually?

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87489/cleaning-unwanted-overlapping-duplicate-meshes)

Comment: @batFINGER That script helped, thank you.

Comment: Cool.. noticed script had a logic error and needed to be run a couple of times, hopefully fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If they have the same names they probably have a trailing `.00x` number behind them. So you could just pick them from the outliner and delete them.

alternatively select the ones you want to keep > ctrl + i to invert selection and delete.