# Quick Way To Delete Overlapping Objects?

Tags: objects

This was ripped from a game, does anyone have any ideas on how to delete objects in the same area? Or maybe a script? I'm open to anything.

[image]

Merge by distance doesn't work by the way

Comment: I honestly can't think of any way to speed it up besides just manually deleting them.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87489/cleaning-unwanted-overlapping-duplicate-meshes The script here works