# how to delete (or select all) all meshes that have no vertices?

Tags: mesh, objects

how to delete all meshes that have no vertices?

some other software in my pipeline generates lots of these "meshes" that contain no mesh data, Is there build in blender function to select all empty meshes (meshes with no vertices) to handle this kind of mess manually?

[image]

Comment: Not sure to understand what you mean with "no vertices" because those looke like vertices to me

Comment: each orange dot is an mesh object with no verticies

Comment: Hello :). Unfortunately Blender seems unable to filter by vertex count. Perhaps a python script would help here.

Comment: Maybe related: [List of objects in scene with counts (verts, faces, tris)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13757/)